# Box content scroll on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have this navigation that can expand when the user clicks a drop down arrow, This navigations is held within a box container with overflow hidden. What I'm trying to achieve is when the users mouse is in the top 20% of the box it scrolls up, and when its in the bottom 20% it scrolls down. I've tried a various number of plugins and tried coding it myself but so far no luck!

This has to be responsive so I am working in percentages.

HTML SET UP:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">Where to next? <span>(this title will be fixed)</span></div>
    <ul class="pagesNav">
        <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
        <li class="has_children">
            <a href="#">Page2</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Child3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Take a look at my fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/7d8fA/**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired effect by this :

```
var height=$('.container').height();
var top20=(height/100)*20;
var top80=height-top20;
$('.container').mouseover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ((e.clientY-e.currentTarget.offsetTop)<top20) {
        $(".container").animate({
           scrollTop: 0
        }, 10);
    } else if (e.clientY>top80) {
        $(".container").animate({
           scrollTop: height
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/U5Uk8/**